# Is there a way to schedule mail messages using the API?

Tags: google-app-maker

Recently, google added the "Schedule send" function to gmail. Is there anyway to call this functionality using the API? I'm using

GmailApp.sendEmail("eMail", "subject", "message");

to send e-mail inside app maker scripts, however, in my use case, I need to send a mail and then schedule 2 other messages.
Do you guys know if this is currently possible?

Thanks,

Comment: It would not appear that they have incorporated this functionality into the Gmail API. You may be able to get something similar accomplished using script triggers server side, but I would think that would get unmanageable pretty quick depending on your follow up message work flow. I would think it would require a separate table to store your triggers along with the recipient and message using a variation of this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder and this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers.

Comment: Also, it I am uncertain how many triggers you can have associated with a script so there might be a limitation. Also keep in mind that this functionality is limited currently even within Gmail to 100 scheduled messages. Looks like trigger limitations are set at 20/user/script, so doing individual triggers for each email would probably not work.